# hello everyone, in python I'd like to return just the names that contains e.g "p' . what should I do?

Tags: python, nested-lists

```
List1 = [
    [
        {"name": " Mahdi", "lastName": "Ashari", "age": 35},
        {"name": "Fatemeh", "lastName": "Dalirian", "age": 25},
    ],
    [
        {"name": " Mohammad", "lastName": "Dalirian", "age": 30},
        {"name": "Maedeh", "lastName": "Poorzamani", "age": 23},
    ],
]

newList = [person["name"] for group in List1 for person in group]
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing just one `if` in the list comprehension:

```
print(
    [
        person["name"]
        for group in List1
        for person in group
        if "P" in person["lastName"]
    ]
)
```

prints out `["Maedeh"]`.

Comment: Note it's only the first letter of the last name then (P is maj) => you could change to ```i "p" in person["lastName"].lower()``` if you look for a "p" in the whole name

Comment: but the code is ok. when I look up for "z" it returns "poorzamani" by the way, thanks so much. you've been really helpful